# What is the meaning of ${var#?} in a shell script

Tags: shell

I don't kanow what #? mean, I goolged,found nothing

the full file: [tinode/chat](https://github.com/tinode/chat/blob/master/build-all.sh)

```
goplat=( darwin windows linux )
# Supported CPU architectures: amd64
goarc=( amd64 )
# Supported database tags
dbtags=( mysql mongodb rethinkdb )

for line in $@; do
  eval "$line"
done

version=${tag#?}

if [ -z "$version" ]; then
  # Get last git tag as release version. Tag looks like 'v.1.2.3', so strip 'v'.
  version=`git describe --tags`
  version=${version#?}
fi
```

Comment: BTW, this script is generally dangerous and not something anyone should ever run. Expanding `$@` unquoted behaves just like unquoted `$*` (which is to say, it's subject to unwanted side effects like string splitting and glob expansion), and use of `eval` without good cause is [strongly frowned on](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Combining the two, you can get nasty effects like an argument containing a whitespace-surrounded `*` causing names of files in the current directory being evaluated as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${tag#?}` expands to the value of `$tag` with the first character deleted.

Quoting the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> `${parameter#[word]}`
>   **Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.** The *word* shall be
>   expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then
>   result in *parameter*, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched
>   by the pattern deleted. If present, *word* shall not begin with an
>   unquoted `'#'`.

In this case the pattern is `?`, which matches a single character.

If you're using bash, the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) also covers this (you can view the manual on your system with `info bash`):

```
'${PARAMETER#WORD}'
'${PARAMETER##WORD}'
     The WORD is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
     expansion (*note Filename Expansion::).  If the pattern matches the
     beginning of the expanded value of PARAMETER, then the result of
     the expansion is the expanded value of PARAMETER with the shortest
     matching pattern (the '#' case) or the longest matching pattern
     (the '##' case) deleted.  If PARAMETER is '@' or '*', the pattern
     removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
     and the expansion is the resultant list.  If PARAMETER is an array
     variable subscripted with '@' or '*', the pattern removal operation
     is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion
     is the resultant list.
```

Comment: Since the question is not about _bash_, the correct reference would not be the bash man page, but i.e. the section _PARAMETER EXPANSION_ in the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Of course for this concrete question, this amounts to the same, because bash just uses the syntax of sh in this case.

Comment: @user2352151: I just noticed, that, although the question asks about _shell_, the script posted here indeed contains features not in POSIX, but just from the code, we still can not infer, that it is bash. As a first glance, it might also be ksh or zsh, and in both cases the reference to the bash man page would be incorrect too, so please be precise when you are asking something, and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash
tag='123'
version=${tag#?}
echo ${version}  # output is: 23
```

=======
so #? is remove first character?

Comment: Please don't write a question as an answer. Post a new question instead.